# babel watch support for renaming or moving files

Tags: watch, babeljs

I'm using the babel command with the `--watch` flag to transpile my code.  However, when I move or rename a file, the old version of the file remains in the output directory.  Is there any way to tell babel to do a clean when something like this happens or should I just switch to chokidar and do it myself?

Comment: Do you use gulp/grunt?

Comment: No. But if it can be done in either let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [gulp-babel-wrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel-wrap) package

Seems like first option from Available tasks: section makes what you need - clean - wipes the destination directory (default 'dist'

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer but it sorta defeats the purpose. One big plus of using the watch is that it only transpiles the files that change. If the entire dist dir is cleaned then it has to redo everything.